# AngularJS HTML template/snippet management

Tags: angularjs, ngboilerplate

I'm an Angular noob coming from Backbone+Marionette+Require.

If you have an app with a bunch of views and a bunch of directives each with their own HTML where are you putting all the HTML snippets? Most of the examples I see are storing them either inline, in their own script tags, or loaded asynchronously.  One thing I love about RequireJS is that templates can live in their own files but can be compiled into the main JS file for production. I assume there's a grunt task or something similar?  Maybe one that takes HTML from individual files and embeds them into individual script tags in a consolidated HTML file at build time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a Grunt task to do this! Originally created by the [Angular-UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap) team, the [`html2js`](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate/blob/master/build/grunt-html2js.js) task will take your templates and compile them into a JavaScript file (using angular's [`$templateCache`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache)) that can be concatenated with the rest of your scripts to form a single payload.

I haven't released it yet as I am still adding documentation, but take a look at [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate), an AngularJS project kickstarter, to see it in context.

**Update (28 Feb 2013):** I just made a release of ngBoilerplate. You can check out the official site here: http://bit.ly/ngBoilerplate.

Comment: Juuiiicy. That's the sauce. Thanks! Looking forward to an official release!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. I've made an initial release. It's not all it can be - yet. Feel free to contribute: http://bit.ly/ngBoilerplate