# AngularJS home page performance concern

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am trying to build an Mobile Web application. As I started writing controllers, services and routes for various functionalities the index.html JS and CSS include seems to be growing day by day. For example, When I start writing controller, services for any functionality then am forced to include them in index.html. I am thinking there is a fundamental problem with the coding approach. If my home page route is "/home" or "/" then home.html should download only JS and CSS files related to home page. But home.html(view) seems to download the entire Javascript and CSS library for every page. How should I design my app in such a way only the functionality related controller, services, directives Javascript files should be downloaded for a page. I appreciate if anyone can explain with a simple example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common/icomoon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/angular/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pdp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pdp_751_1.css">

<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.touchwipe.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is the route provider for the main app... -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/c-home.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/c-browse.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/c-product-details.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/directives/d-product-details.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/s-home.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/s-browse.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/s-product-details.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/iscroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: In a production environment you should not have these many files, you need to combine these files and minify them

Comment: @Arun, If I don't include these files then the route provider will throw an error since it wont be able to find the controller.All the routes are initialized during the loading of index.html so angular will try to load the corresponding controllers

Comment: You need to look at caching of these static files so that these need not be downloaded every time along with combining and minifying the files will do

Comment: Caching is one solution in general we are leaning towards but all the javascript and css files related to entire application should be index.html. is this how angularJS works? Cant we inject them on the specific html page?

Comment: is it a single page app

Comment: @LachuT As of right now, there is no way to lazy-load code; but in production, you should concatenate all of these into a single minified payload. Check out my [ngBoilerplate](http://bit.ly/ngBoilerplate) project for an example. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15103574/259038) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: can append `<link>` tags to head on an as needed basis also

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry so much about the combined payload size of your files, but more about the build process and making sure to reduce HTTP requests as much as possible (1 css, 1 js is all you should have in your home.html). This is more important. Also minify everything. I suggest you check out ng-boilerplate. Its a starting point for angular apps and has most of the best practices you should be employing.

https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate

Make sure to read all the readme files at the various directory levels.